Ehache not working in cluster environment. In ehache map return null value
In a cluster environment with three nodes, node1, node2 and node3, I maintain one map, such as StudentEnchacheMap, where all data from three nodes is stored. After putting data into the map, I had it printed out and all nodes' data was correctly stored.
However, after 2 minutes, I called one API. Using that api i want to check using input id key is present or not if present then get the student value and update into database. But this api is called only by node1.
So when i call this api using id, it's check that entry is present or not into the cache map after adding addition logs i found that what are entries stored by node1 that return value and able to update the student data into database but whenever node2 and node3 ids are comming so in that time it's returns null value from map but accually that value is present into the map what was problem here please provide a solution.
ehcache.xml file configuration
 <cache name="studentStatusPollCount"

            maxElementsInMemory="5000"

            eternal="false"

            timeToIdleSeconds="1300"

            timeToLiveSeconds="1300"

            overflowToDisk="false"

            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">

     <cacheEventListenerFactory

        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"

        properties="replicateAsynchronously=true,

                    replicatePuts=true,

                    replicateUpdates=true,

                    replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true,

                    asynchronousReplicationIntervalMillis=300,

                    replicateRemovals=true"/>

    </cache>

Api which called by all nodes and updates value into ehcache map
public void modifiedEhcacheMap (Student student){
Cache studentStatusMap = ApplicationCacheManager.getInstance().getCacheInstance("studentStatusPollCount");

synchronized (studentStatusMap) {

studentStatusMap.put(new Element(student.getStudnetId(), student));

Student s = (Student)scheduleStatusMap.get(updateStatus.getRunId()).getObjectValue();

LOG.info("Inside StudentUpdate Api  Entry is put into the catche map for runId=============================>" + s.getStudnetId + " "

+ s.getStudentName());

}

List<Object> keys = studentStatusMap.getKeys();

LOG.info("Inside StudentUpdate Api Keyssssss size===============================>" + keys.size());

for (Object s : keys) {

Student stu = (Student)studentStatusMap.get(s).getObjectValue();

if (stu == null) {

LOG.info("Inside FlowchartRunNotifyServlet entry is not present for runid=>>>>>>>>>" + s);

} else {

LOG.info("Inside StudentUpdate Api key iteration=============================>"

+ stu.getId+ "" + .getStudentName());

}

}

}

Polling api which is called by only node1
Student result=null;
Cache studentStatusMap = ApplicationCacheManager.getInstance().getCacheInstance("studentStatusPollCount");

List<Object> keys = studentStatusMap.getKeys();

LOG.info("Inside student polling api Keyssssss size===============================>" + keys.size());

for (Object s : keys) {

Student stu = (Status)studentStatusMap.get(s).getObjectValue();

if (stu == null) {

LOG.info("Inside student polling api entry is not present for runid=>>>>>>>>>" + s);

} else {

LOG.info("Inside student polling api key iteration=============================>"

+ stu.getStudentId() + "" + stu.getStudentName());

}

}

if (studentStatusMap.getSize() > 0 && studentStatusMap.isKeyInCache(runId)) {

synchronized (studentStatusMap) {

result = (Student) studnetStatusMap.get(runId).getObjectValue();

LOG.info(

"Inside student polling api Entry is put into the catche map for runId=============================>"

+ result.getStudentId() + " " + result.getStudnetName());

return result;

}

}


Note(both StudentUpdate and student polling apis key size print same)
LOG.info("Inside StudentUpdate Api Keyssssss size===============================>" + keys.size());
LOG.info("Inside student polling api Keyssssss size===============================>" + keys.size());

I want to know when node2 and node3 IDs are coming to the polling API. At that time I don't want to return null?

Please format / indent your code properly. Also, next time format it properly for StackOverflow. Your question was unreadable.
